# how to convert 10:09:00 GMT+0000 to IST in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm Developing web app, In that We are using CK Editor Calendar. In which I'm execute below code for get `Date & Time` ..

**Code:**

```
var strDate = new Date(event.start);
var endDate = new Date(event.end);

var title='Event :'+event.title+' 
From :'+ event.start.toLocaleString() +'To:'+event.end.toLocaleString()+' By :';
```

**Output:**

```
Fri Feb 13 2015 10:37:00 GMT+0000 To :Fri Feb 13 2015 10:37:00 GMT+0000
```

**Expect Output:**

In the above output it should remove the **GMT+0000**, **Replace the Proper session whether AM/PM**.

Comment: What is the value of *event.start*? *toLocaleString* is implementation dependent, it is intended to show the date in a convenient, human readable form and does not necessarily conform to any standard or convention.

Comment: Fri Feb 13 2015 10:37:00 GMT+0000, Through variable I couldn't get the proper result. Instead of `GMT+0000` I need `Session AM/PM`.

Comment: So what *exact* output do you want? Fri Feb 13 2015 10:37:00 AM?

Comment: Yep RobG. Exact output needed with AM/PM. In any other way can i get it?

Comment: For any sort of consistency, you must parse the string manually, then manually format it. Don't be daunted, parsing is perhaps 4 lines of code (including validating the values), formatting a few more. Have a go, there are many posts here on parsing and formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You included jQuery with your tags, and so I assume you'd be okay using a jQuery plugin. [jQuery-dateFormat](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat) is simple to use.

```js
var date = new Date();
var fDate = $.format.date(date, 'E MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss a');
                          
$('#date').text(fDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat/master/dist/jquery-dateFormat.min.js"></script>

<div id="date"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following function should do what you want. It parses the string to create a date object using UTC values, then adjusts the UTC time to get to IST (+0530), then returns a formatted string with equivalent IST values.

```
// Expects string in format: Fri Feb 13 2015 10:37:00 GMT+0000
// Assumes is UTC
// Returns values in IST
function parseAndFormat(s) {

  // Helper
  function z(n){return (n<10? "0":'') + n;}

  // Split into parts
  var b = s.split(/[ :]/);
  var m = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
  var days = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];

  // Create a date based on UTC values
  var d = new Date(Date.UTC(b[3], m.indexOf(b[1]), b[2], b[4], b[5], b[6]));

  // Add 5 hours 30 minutes to the UTC time -> IST
  d.setUTCHours(d.getUTCHours() + 5, d.getUTCMinutes() + 30);

  // Format the hours for am/pm
  var hr = d.getUTCHours();
  var ap = hr > 11? 'PM' : 'AM';
  hr = hr%12 || 12;

  // Format the output based on the adjusted UTC time
  var dt = days[d.getUTCDay()] + ' '
           + m[d.getUTCMonth()] + ' '
           + d.getUTCDate() + ' '
           + d.getUTCFullYear() + ' '
           + z(hr) + ':'
           + z(d.getUTCMinutes()) + ':'
           + z(d.getUTCSeconds()) + ' '
           + ap;
  return dt;
}

console.log(parseAndFormat('Fri Feb 13 2015 10:37:00 GMT+0000')) // Fri Feb 13 2015 04:07:00 PM

console.log(parseAndFormat('Fri Feb 13 2015 20:37:00 GMT+0000')) // Sat Feb 14 2015 02:07:00 AM
```

This method would work with local values except where daylight saving gets in the way. Note that this is always IST, it will not adjust for daylight saving observed in places that use it.

#### Edit

Fixed 12hr conversion.